# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL while uploading JSON object

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs

This is the code on server side, please help me to understand where I am going wrong. 
I am uploading an byte array of image as JSON object. Converting the byte array and saving it on disk.

```
package com.file.up;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/")

public class FileUp {

    @POST
    @Path("/crunchifyService")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Response crunchifyREST(JSONObject incomingData) {
        String s="Success!";
        try {

            String jsonString = incomingData.getString("image");
            byte[] a=jsonString.getBytes();

            InputStream input=new ByteArrayInputStream(a);
            BufferedImage b=ImageIO.read(input);
            ImageIO .write(b,"png",new File("C:\\Users\\Uma\\Desktop\\WEB_AND"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
        }
        System.out.println("Data Received: ");

        // return HTTP response 200 in case of success
        return Response.status(200).entity(s).build();
    }
}
```

This is my client side code.

```
package com.file.up;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection; 
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class FileClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image;
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("12.png"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write( image, "png", baos );
    baos.flush();
    byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
    String base64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageInByte);
    baos.close();

        // Step2: Now pass JSON File Data to REST Service
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"image\":\"" + base64String + "\"}");
            System.out.println(jsonObject);
            URL url = new URL("http://<ip>:9999/FileUpload/api/crunchifyService");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
           // out.write(jsonObject.toString());
            out.close();



           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                   connection.getInputStream()));

           while (in.readLine() != null) {
            }
            System.out.println("\nREST Service Invoked Successfully..");
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\nError while calling REST Service");
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

And the stack trace is
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://:9999/FileUpload/api/crunchifyService
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1838)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at com.file.up.FileClient.main(FileClient.java:64)

Comment: Can you see the server log? It might show something that is causing the exception.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is my server log :   com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the paths:
  C:\jeresy webapp\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\FileUpload\WEB-INF\lib
  C:\jeresy webapp\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\FileUpload\WEB-INF\classes
Dec 22, 2014 10:08:50 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig init
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.file.up.FileUp
Dec 22, 2014 10:08:50 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig init
INFO: Provider classes found:

Comment: Those are just INFO logs. Are there any exceptions being thrown? I would imagine the cause of the 500 would be logged.

Comment: No exception is being thrown

Comment: If I change my server side as  :   public Response crunchifyREST(InputStream incomingData) that is instead of JSONObject if I make it InputStream. the server side is atleast getting executed(though with exceptions). What should I do?

Comment: Did you even try to use a String as I suggested in my deleted answer? And what's the exception?

Comment: Actually I could not really get that. Sorry.  The Exception is :     java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
        at com.file.up.FileUp.crunchifyREST(FileUp.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) But I think this exception is their because I ams ending an Image as JSON and consuming a InputStream

Comment: But I am unable to understand that why JSONObject doesnt work and InputStream does

Comment: You might need to add the JSON support. See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#json.low.level.approach.section). There is an example you can download

Answer (score 0):

I copied your classes in my TomEE server and from the client I am getting no body on the request, you should try using a jaxrs client